# Какова актуальность Java апплетов?

Tags: java

В книге Программирование на java для детей родителей бабушек и дедушек изучается программирование на Swing с написанием игры крестики нолики с последующией публикацией игры на web через апплет.
Правильно ли я понимаю что таким образом мы пишем игру на Java (Swing, JavaFX) и публикуем её на нашем сайте для пользования онлайн? Например можно ли написать дурака таким образом для игры на двоих?
Или это все делается через Java web? И можно ли вообще не зная (Java FX и Swing) написать крестики нолики или дурака чисто инструментами для Java web?
Прошу прощение за возможно глупый вопрос, но в предыдущем вопросе мне был дан ответ что технологии Java (Swing, FX) и Java web разные. Вот мне и интересно.
Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что написано в Вашей книге, т.к. её не читал, но апплеты уже давным давно `Deprecated` (устаревший функционал) и сегодня их используют только в очень старых проектах. А начиная с Java 11 их поддержка полностью исключена.

Изучите для начала Java SE. А потом в зависимости от того, что Вам ближе, будете продвигаться либо в desktop направлении, либо в Web.

Только книги для изучения берите не очень старые. Хотя бы Java 7 или 8.

Comment: Спасибо большое!
Скажите, Java SE относится к десктопу или эта база и под Web и под Дестоп?

Comment: И скажите пожалуйста что используется сейчас вместо апплетов?

Comment: Вместо апплетов сейчас использую Java под web. Если что, это один из компонентов Java EE.

Comment: @Streletz простите но совершенно не понятно про что Вы, какая такая java под веб из java ee?

Comment: Сервлеты, JSP...

Comment: @Streletz человек спрашивает не как сервер сайд сделать, а как формочку нарисовать

Comment: Формочку можно и на том же JSP нарисовать. А, апплеты, про которые он спрашивает уже давно практически полностью ушли в историю.